# What does a large t-statistic mean?

Tags: multiple-regression, t-test

I am empirically studying Fama & French three factors (market, SMB, HML - independent variables) model on a Viet Nam stock exchange. The dataset is daily stocks' return during almost 4 years. The stocks are grouped in six portfolios - each is dependent variable in each regression. I would like to test the validity of Fama & French three factor model in explaining excess return of portfolios. Below is regression output of one of the portfolios, with a really high t-statistics. Any problem with that?

```
            Coefficients    Standard Error        t Stat    P-value
Intercept       0.00191         0.00031          6.27072    0.00000
RPt = Rmt - Rf  0.98782         0.01737         56.85940    0.00000
SMB             0.87223         0.02796         31.19128    0.00000
HML             0.68983         0.02172         31.76355    0.00000
```

Please let me know if it's unclear.

Comment: You could simply have an extremely large n. Or (multi)collinearity. Hard to say. Could you edit your question to tell us a little more about your dataset and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @StephanKolassa: thank you, i edited the question. btw, the exact number of observation is 937.

Comment: Hm. I am not familiar with the Fama-French model, but judging from Wikipedia, it looks like the three regressors should not be highly collinear, so this may be genuine and not a problem, given your n. You may still want to look at Variance Inflation Factors, just in case.

Comment: Collinearity increases the Std. Err. (that's why it's called Variance Inflation) and therefore does not lead to very high t-statistics. There are however other problems like the fact that the stock returns are not independent observations and you should use time series models.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**My Answer:** Those numbers are probably okay. What is the basis for this assertion? I simply had a look through the source material:

Fama, E. F. and French, K. R. (1993) Common risk factors in the returns on stock and bonds, Journal of Financial Economics, 33, 3–56

In particular, have a look at table 6 (on p24). You'll see that the numbers they get are roughly similar to the numbers you are getting. Of course, it is impossible to say for sure given that you've only posted the results for one of your portfolios. I recommend going and seeing if the numbers for all your portfolios are "in the ball-park" of the numbers in the aforementioned table.

One other thing, I think you mean "uncorrelated" when you say "independent" regarding Market, SMB, HML.

**My Rant:** The regression based approach of Fama and French is really not the right way to go about tackling this problem. Essentially, in the estimation of the regression coefficients, you are assuming the model is correctly specified. But ultimately the specification of the model is the very thing you then try and test with the regression coefficients. A much better approach to this problem can be found in:

Bai, J., Ng, S. (2006) "Evaluating latent and observed factors in macroeconomics and finance", Journal of Econometrics 131, pp507-537.

Also, given that I've taken the time to write out this answer, I'm going to shamelessly plug a paper of my own on this subject :-)

Colin T. Bowers & Chris Heaton (2013): What does high-dimensional factor analysis tell us about risk factors in the Australian stock market?, Applied Economics, 45:11, 1395-1404

Comment: Welcome to our site, Colin!

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the welcome! I was here on an unrelated topic, but spotted something familiar :-)

Comment: @ColinTBowers: below is the results of all portfolios, most of them are high.
 t(α) t(β1) t(β2) t(β3)
SH 6.271 56.859 31.191 31.764
SM 5.894 44.166 18.266 10.538
SL 3.922 37.793 22.517 -18.177
BH 4.078 39.354 -3.408 16.034
BM 6.733 50.572 -2.848 1.783
BL 6.498 58.972 -9.253 -8.834

by independent i mean explaining.

Comment: @hung Okay, the numbers are a little higher than Fama & French (1993) (not sure about constants, F&F don't give those) - but not beyond the realms of possibility. Please, do check that table for yourself so you can put your mind at ease. High explanatory power is likely in these regressions since regressors and regressands are both constructed from the same underlying random variables (ie stock returns). Point taken about "independent" - I tend to use regressor/regressand to try and avoid the confusion :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is generally not a problem. It just means, for each coefficient, that if you assume it really is zero, and the effects you see in the estimated coefficient are simply due to sampling error (the randomness inherent in taking a random sample), your data are extremely unlikely. Your high t-statistic, which translates into a low p-value, simply says that something very unlikely has happened if your coefficients are zero in reality.

You can take the output of your regression as (statistical, that is, quantitative, not definitive) evidence of an effect (not causality, rather an association between the concerning independent and your dependent variable). Neither t-statistic nor p-value (which have a one-to-one correspondence here through the t distribution) make a statement about effect size. So you can be somewhat sure there is an effect. That's what the high t statistic means here.